# perls, array, variable length of array

Tags: arrays, perl

I wish to modify one particular line in perl script :

```
@list = ([$tmp[0],$tmp[1],$tmp[2]]);
```

I have change it to this:

```
if( $input == 3 )
{
        @list = ([$tmp[0],$tmp[1],$tmp[2]]);
}
if( $input == 2 )
{
        @list = ([$tmp[0],$tmp[1]]);
}
if( $input == 1 )
{
        @list = ([$tmp[0]]);
}
```

Above code works, but I would like it to works with `$input` values up to 40 .

I try few different approaches but I am not able to code it in more elegant way, which really bother me.

Much appreciated any help with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following does what you requested:

```
@list = [ @tmp[ 0 .. $input-1 ] ];
```

The following does what you want:

```
my @list = @tmp[ 0 .. $input-1 ];
```

You can also do the latter in-place very efficiently using the following:

```
splice(@tmp, $input);
```

Comment: I tested both, what I requested ( as you put it ) is what works in program I modify, thank you.

Comment: It's using an array to store a single value (a reference to the array that contains the actual values), which is silly.

Comment: (Unless, you add more to it later)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`array slice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices), which will return a list of elements from the `@tmp` array that you are interested in:

```
my @list = @tmp[0..$input-1];
```

The basic idea is that you copy the elements starting at index 0 to the maximum index you are interested in `$input`.